# Reusing GMF Dashboard

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

Eclipse GMF supports creation of GMF diagram through GMF dashboard.

We would like to create similar dashboard, and I was wondering if this component
is reusable and if yes, where can I find some example of doing this.

[image: GMF Dashboard]

Comment: Take a look here: org.eclipse.gmf.internal.bridge.ui.dashboard

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was hopping that this component is flexible and reusable. Well, it is still good thing to see the idea how to develop something like this.